# Compare and equals methods stack overflow error

Tags: java, compare, project, equals

Hi this is my first time asking a question so it may not be the best. 
So I'm working on a project using inheritance and implementation. My problem is when I run my compare or equals methods java gives me a stack overflow error and I have looked everywhere to solve this but am unable to do so. It might just be a simple I don't exactly know what to ask for though.

```
//this is from the class that inherits
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if(this.equals(o)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
//This is what its inheriting from
public boolean equals(Object o){
    boolean findings;
    findings = this.getStrength().equals(((Weapon)o).getStrength());
    if(strength == ((Weapon)o).strength){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//this code is an instance of another
@Override
public int compareTo(Force o) {
    return this.compareTo(o);
}
```

Any advice you could give would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
public class Pizza extends Store {
public Pizza(int strong){
    super.changeStrength(strong);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if(o!=null){
        if(super.getStrength()==((Pizza)o).getStrength()){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

here the code for the pizza class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to below method to avoid the recursion as you are calling the same equals method from the equals method. `this` refers to the same class and since you have overidden the equals method it calls the same method and becomes recursive without any exit condition. the StackOverFlowError tells you that its stuck in the recursive loop.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if(super.equals(o)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

### UPDATE

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Pizza)) return false;

    Pizza pizza = (Pizza) o;

    return getStrength() == pizza.getStrength();
}
```

Comment: Ok now I just have one more problem. I'm using a tester for this project and it says that they do not equal when run

Comment: pizza1 = new Pizza(63);
  pizza2 = new Pizza(63);
  actual = pizza1.equals(pizza2);
  assertTrue("Incorrect result", actual);  

This is the tester code

Comment: You need to implement `equals` method in the Pizza class for execution to know how to compare Pizza object for equality.

Comment: @Override
 public boolean equals(Object o){
  if(super.equals(o)){
   return true;
  }
  return false;
 }

Like this?

Comment: Just added to the post